# compact open subgroups of a totally disconnected locally compact group are commensurable

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I'm having a little trouble proving that any two subgroups of a totally disconnected, locally compact topological group are commensurable, so am looking for a push in the right direction!

I have so far a proof that shows that some subgroup $H$ of the group $G$ is commensurated by the group $G$, but this relies on the fact that I can conjugate $H$ by some $g \in G$ and then use the intersection $H \cap gHg^{-1}$ -- at which point it's trivial to just examine the cosets of this group to see that the index is finite (thanks to a finite subcover) and thus commensurability is proven.

At this point, I'm considering using the properties of the index function; specifically that $[H : H \cap K] \leq [G : K]$; since $[G : K]$ is finite (by the same argument as above), $[H : H \cap K]$ must be too. Is this the right direction to be headed, or is there something fundamental that I'm missing that makes this glaringly wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that any compact open subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$ of any (Hausdorff) topological group $G$ are commensurable, because the intersection $G_1\cap G_2$ is a compact open subgroup of the group $G$, therefore $G_1\cap G_2$ is a compact open subgroup of both $G_1$ and $G_2$. Thus both indexes $[G_1:G_1\cap G_2]$ and $[G_2:G_1\cap G_2]$ are finite.

Comment: This seems simpler than what I had in mind -- though does that make my current idea incorrect?